# connect-redis.redis and ioredis.redis type incompatibility

Tags: typescript, ioredis

I'm trying to deploy my server (nodejs, typescript) but can't build the project because of a type mismatch. Everything works fine, but this type error is the only one appearing when I do yarn watch

error message:

```
Type 'import("/usr/src/app/node_modules/@types/ioredis/index").Redis' is not assignable to 
type 'import("/usr/src/app/node_modules/@types/connect-redis/node_modules/@types/ioredis/index").Redis'
Types of property 'hset' are incompatible.
index.d.ts(91, 9): The expected type comes from property 'client' which is declared here on type 'RedisStoreOptions'
```

`src/index.js`

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';

const app = express();

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);

app.use(
    session({
      name: COOKIE_NAME,
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redis,
        disableTouch: true
      }),
      ...
```

Everything seems perfectly functional, besides I was following Ben Awad's React Fullstack tutorial and my source code is exactly the same as his, so it must be something in the types (node modules maybe?). How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Not a robust solution but this answer https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/300#issuecomment-580038867 worked for me, adding `as any` to the client

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing in order to be able to build.